# PHP DateTime in Object Doesn't Maintain Original Value In Loop

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have array in PHP which contains a date and the amount of days I want to add to that date. As I am looping over these dates and adding the specified amount, the [date] values on each loop keeps getting incremented with each pass of the loop. Here is my array...

```
        Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-10 06:00:00.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 2
                        [timezone] => GMT
                    )

                [daysToAdd] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-10 06:00:00.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 2
                        [timezone] => GMT
                    )

                [daysToAdd] => 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [date] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-10 06:00:00.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 2
                        [timezone] => GMT
                    )

                [daysToAdd] => 10
            )

    )
```

I am passing all of this data to a function to process it...

```
->processDates($data);
```

Inside of my PHP function...

```
foreach($array['dates'] as $day){
        $originalDateTime = $day['date']; # original dateTime
        $dateTime = $day['date']; # the dateTime as a new var
        $dateTime = $dateTime->modify('+'.$day['daysToAdd'].' days'); // modify the dateTime
        print_r([
            'originalDate'=>$originalDateTime,
            'newDate'=>$dateTime,
        ]);
    }
```

This is what happens when the first element is ran inside of the function...

```
!!! The original date is also incremented by the value passed when I added it back to the array, even though i set it as a completely unmodified variable inside of the function !!!

    Array
    (
        [originalDate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-13 06:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => GMT
            )

        [newDate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-13 06:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => GMT
            )

    )

This is what happens when the second element is ran inside of the function...

    Array
    (
        [originalDate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-18 06:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => GMT
            )

        [newDate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-18 06:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => GMT
            )

    )
```

And this is what happens on the 3rd iteration...

```
    Array
    (
        [originalDate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-28 06:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => GMT
            )

        [newDate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-10-28 06:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => GMT
            )

    )
```

Each time I loop over the array the original datetime gets messed up by the ->modify. How can I prevent this so that each loop completely gets reset and uses the actual data passed in. I need the ['originalDate'] to maintain as originally set as "2017-10-10 06:00:00.000000"...

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: Use `DateTimeImmutable` instead > http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php

Comment: You loop over the same object(s), even if you have different variables (containing these same object(s)). See the comments: clone or use immutables.